# How to find random numbers in input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the print statement to print the number in the range between the low and upper.

I keep getting the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "python", line 5, in <module> ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()
```

From the program:

```
from random import*
lowRange = input('What is the lower range number?')
hiRange = input('What is the higher range nunmber?')

ran = randrange (lowRange,hiRange)
print (ran)
```

Comment: lowrange and highrange is string ,  convert it to integer by `int(lowrange)` and `int(highrange)`

Answer (score 2):

The `input()` function always returns a string. If you want to use integers, as in this case, you have to convert those strings to integers using `int()`. However, if the user enters something that cannot be converted to an integer (e.g. 'hi', or just hitting return), you will get an error when trying to convert. To deal with that, you will want to look into try and except statements. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

In here until you enter a number it wouldn't stop. Inputs other than `int` will take as an invalid input.

What's wrong in your code is everything reads from input is taken as a string.

```
from random import*
while True:
        try:
            lowRange = int(input('What is the lower range number?'))
            break
        except:
            print("That's not a valid input!")
while True:
        try:
            hiRange = int(input('What is the higher range nunmber?'))
            break
        except:
            print("That's not a valid input!")

ran = randrange (lowRange,hiRange)
print (ran)
```